# How to change port no of the jboss 4.2 server

Tags: eclipse-indigo, jboss-4.2.x

I have to different eclipse ide and jboss server.I need to start both the server at a time but problem is what when I try to start the second server it gives error(port conflict as the first one is using it already).Please guide me to how to change the port no of jboss 4.2

Answer (score 3):

You can change the port of JBoss 4 as detailed in "[How to change port 8080 in JBoss?](http://www.digizol.com/2006/09/jboss-4-how-to-change-port-8080-in.html)".

> 1. Goto the deploy folder of the server instance you use.
> 2. Goto the jbossweb-tomcat55.sar inside that deploy folder.
> 3. Find the file named server.xml inside that folder. (tomcat service file).

Then look at the Connector configuration in that file.